# How to use ssh tunneling for local development?

Tags: linux, http, networking, ssh, proxy

I am developing against an API which whitelists IP addresses. The office is whitelisted, but my coffeeshop is not. I have ssh access to a box that is whitelisted I can use for ssh tunneling. If I set up the SOCKS proxy like this, then I can change my network preferences (on a mac) to use it.

```
ssh -N -D 12345 sean@NNN.NNN.NNN.NNN -p NNNN
```

If I go to http://canyouseeme.org, my IP address is shown as coming from the whitelisted IP.

But my terminal sessions don't seem to be using the proxy. I am developing an application, and I need to test the code that integrates with the API, and have the HTTP traffic appear to come from the ssh box.

How can I test the app I'm developing through the ssh tunnel?

Comment: You haven't told us anything about this app you're developing. How would any of us know how to make it use a socks proxy?

Comment: You need an application to be able to communicate using SOCKS proxy. If your application does not support that, you can use normal remote port forwarding using `-R` switch to `ssh`.

Comment: To be clear, I don't want my application to support SOCKS. It doesn't need to. I want my terminal to use the proxy during local development.

Answer (score 0):

[SSHuttle](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle) worked perfectly. Install via homebrew or their instructions, then:

```
 sshuttle -r user@NNN.NNN.NNN.NNN:NNNN 0.0.0.0/0
```

And all my traffic in terminal goes through the proxy, including the app I'm developing locally.